# Paypal IPN Validation - Doesn't work despite success page being reached

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I've been bashing my head against a brick wall the last few days on minor problems.  This time I am on the final piece to the puzzle.  In my php function of a wordpress cart plugin I have the following:

Relevant Function - http://codepad.org/uDm3q9yp

Paypal Class - http://codepad.org/friBthoO

I manage to go through the purchase fine.  If I check on the sandbox account the seller receives the correct email from paypal and money etc.  The case "IPN" in the function doesn't seem to work however.  No email is sent with details.  The success case is reached with a thank you page shown though.  I don't understand how I could have missed anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'll be straight forward I'm not gonna sit here and test your script, but I understand the pain of trouble shooting an IPN script from my past experience so I'll share some tips:

- use a IPN tester/simulator: https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNTesting

  - check if it can reach your script address
  - check if your script is communicating back
  - check if you are getting a VALID response back from Paypal

    - if this works check where Paypal is sending its IPN info to the right script
- try storing all of the POST information from Paypal IPN into a database to debug or look at the GET string on Paypal's site under IPN history
- variables are URL encoded make sure you decode them

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't really expect to find an answer but I've ran out of things to try, change around, test etc.  I actually tried using the simulator before but will have another play around.

Comment: For other people having the same problem and have time.  Suggest reading this guide- http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html#s1

Comment: It's crucial that you record information every step of the way because it can crap out at any time, worse IPN can be down or slow.

Comment: By adding various emails at different stages I figured out the IPN is being passed on.  It is not being validated though.

Comment: So it is not able to validate the data with paypal correct? I would check if the method used is allowed on your server (fsock, curl) are you on godaddy by any chance?

Comment: I am hostgator.  That might be a possibility.  Is there a way to email all available data received from paypal, to prove it holds the data?  Im beginning to suspect its the age of the class which is the problem.  I don't really have the expertise to be fixing this I think.

Comment: Okay, I managed to output the data by sending it as an email after validation (using else, so when validation fails).  I can see all the data but now to figure out why validation fails: http://codepad.org/XLaZ6MFi

Comment: It also populates the table if I put the code when validation fails.  Obviously that isnt secure.

Comment: So all I need to figure out, what in the following function causes validation to fail for the data shown in the above link - http://codepad.org/XkxrgmNn

Comment: What initially sticks out is the absence of payment_gross: and 
payment_fee:, maybe a change in api from paypal causes them not to be passed?  Just read payment_gross is for USD only.  Maybe if I change to USD it will verify and prove that is the problem.

Comment: Well that didn't work.  The gross isn't empty now but it still doesnt pass validation.

Comment: Check if hostgator is blocking you `$this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);` this is verifying the data with the server. Btw if you are using a test server you need to make sure the fgets is pointed to the right server

Comment: How would I check that?  I also thought if it was blocked it would show up in the error log?

Comment: Well I added the example code with a lipsum txt file.  It displays the document without error, surely means fopen isnt disabled http://intelligentstudios.co.uk/test-ipn/test-fgets.php

Comment: I would check line 18 to see where the if statement goes and check `$this->ipn_response`

Comment: It appears to be connecting fine.  I get no mailed errors when I added a simple mail function.  I get the following for IPN response, maybe im just shattered and doing something stupid though:  HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
Server: BigIP
Connection: close

Comment: Possibly related to: https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services ?

Comment: I think I've cracked it.  If I change:$fp = fsockopen($url_parsed[host],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);  to  $fp = fsockopen('ssl://'.$url_parsed[host],"443",$err_num,$err_str,30); the details are added to the table after passing validation.

Comment: Hallelujah, thank you so much David, it seems to be functioning as expected after the change.